# android CountDownTimer lag

Tags: android, listview, countdowntimer

im trying CountDownTimer on android studio and it works fine, but after about 5 minutes passed apps seems to badly lag. how to prevent this?

*note :
my logcat give this warning **"Skipped 60 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread."**

and im using this CountDownTimer for a listview, so there is a CountDownTimer as listview item (if the item less or equal to 2 items there is no problem so far).

here is my code :

```js
        int milis = Integer.valueOf(timeinseconds[position]);
        myTimer = new CountDownTimer(milis, 1000) {
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                tempminute = (int) Math.floor((millisUntilFinished/1000)/60);
                minutes = tempminute%60;
                seconds = (int) (millisUntilFinished/1000)%60;
                hours = tempminute/60;

                vouchercountdown.setText("00 day " + hours + " hr " + minutes + " min " + seconds + " sec");

            }

            public void onFinish() {
                vouchercountdown.setText("00 day 00 hr 00 min 00 sec");
            }
        };

        Runnable mHandlerTask = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                myTimer.start();
            }
        };
        mHandlerTask.run();
```

Thanks

Comment: You can try starting the timer in a separate Thread/Runnable.

Comment: how to do that janki ?

Comment: Take a look on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27715602/android-countdowntimer-class-lagging-main-thread

Comment: still the same after 5 min and apps start to lagging